# Android passar Token de autenticação no header usando Volley

Tags: android, volley

Estou tendo dificuldades para enviar token de autenticação no header utilizando volley

Este é o meu código

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    Log.i("onActivityCreated: ", "token: ====> " + deliverymanEntitie.getTokenEntitie().getToken());

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
    String url = RunfoxService.URL_GET_ALL_ORDERS_TO(deliverymanEntitie.getId());
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(StringRequest.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.i("onResponse: ", response);
        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            try {
                String json = new String(error.networkResponse.data, "UTF-8");
                Log.e("onErrorResponse: ", json);
                Log.e("onErrorResponse: ", error.networkResponse.headers.toString());


            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }) {

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Content-type", "application/application/json; charset=UTF-8");
            headers.put("Accept", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
            headers.put("api_token", deliverymanEntitie.getTokenEntitie().getToken());

            Log.i("getHeaders: ", headers.toString());

            return headers;
        }
    };

    queue.add(stringRequest);

}
```

No código acima temos toda a requisição realizada, aqui estão meus logs

log de erro da minha api

```
E/onErrorResponse:: {"message":"Token de acesso n\u00e3o informado"}
```

Testando com o Postman a mesma requisição e infirmando também no header o token eu consigo ter o resultado do json corretamente.

Aparentemente não estou conseguindo informar o token no headers, alguém sabe me dizer onde estou errando?

Comment: Pela sua descrição, a única coisa que pode estar acontecendo é `deliverymanEntitie.getTokenEntitie().getToken()` estar retornando null ou vazio. Já colocou alguns breakpoints ai, debugou e viu que de fato ta vindo um token dessa função?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi meu problema simplementes removendo o "_" do api_token ficando assim:

```
headers.put("apitoken", deliverymanEntitie.getTokenEntitie().getToken());
```

dessa forma consegui passar e receber na minha API, não sei afundo sobre o motivo mas funcionou pra mim.